# Why does the Python documentation call [1, 2] a list "display" instead of a "literal"?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set, literals

The Python documentation calls `[1, 2]` a "[list display](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#list-displays)".

Similarly, it calls `{1, 2}` a "[set display](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#set-displays)" and `{1:'a', 2:'b'}` a "[dictionary display](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays)".

Why is "display" used instead of the more common term, "literal"?

Comment: Nowhere in that documentation does it says [1, 2] is a list display. What? It says `list_display ::=  "[" [starred_list | comprehension] "]"` is a list display. That's a completely different kind of statement from `list = [1,2]`.

Comment: @DetectivePikachu No, it's not. Despite the name, a starred list doesn't actually have to contain a star. The starred list in this case is `1,2`. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget That's not what the term "display" refers to here.

Answer (score 2):

From the first paragraph of the [preceding section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries):

> For constructing a list, a set or a dictionary Python provides special
>   syntax called “displays”, each of them in two flavors:
>
> - either the container contents are listed explicitly, or
> - they are
>     computed via a set of looping and filtering instructions, called a
>     comprehension.

A display is the general term that comprises "literals" and comprehensions.

`[1, foo(x), "bar"]` is a list literal (ignoring the fact that `foo(x)` has to be evaluated first).

`[foo(x) for x in A]` is a list comprehension.

Both are list displays.

---

As @r.ook points out, the language reserves the term [*literal*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals), strictly speaking, for expressions that produce *constant* values of types like `str` and `int`.

The constant aspect is critical, if you want to explain why `f'{x}'` is a literal but `[1]` is not. The former is computed at run-time, but the resulting string is fixed, while `[1]` can create a list at compile time, but that list can be mutated later.

Comment: Also, [*Literals are notations for constant values of some built-in types.*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals).  `list`s, `set`s and `dict`s are not constants.